# Conditional filter: Only for controllers that inherit from baseController and is a post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter, ninject.web.mvc, global-filter

How to apply a global filter for all actions where the controler inherits `baseController` and is a post?

### Attempt

Already working with [Ninject.Web.MVC](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) aka `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax`

But I do not know how to apply conditional `BindFilter` only to post.

`kernel.BindFilter<ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Action, 0).WhenControllerType<baseController>();`  ...??

This attempt did not work, because I could not add two conditions to BindFilter

[image: Conditions]
[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyRwC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do something similar to this.  One way to do it is to implement your multiple conditions inside of `When()`.  The `WhenControllerType()` method is just a helper that calls `When()` and checks the controller type, so you can re-implement that in your own method and add in whatever other logic you need.

Here is how Ninject implements `WhenControllerType()`:

```
public IFilterBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenControllerType(Type controllerType)
{
    this.When((Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, bool>) ((controllerContext, actionDescriptor) => (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == controllerType)));
    return this;
}
```

From that, we know how to get the controller type for our constraint.

To get a binding like you want, we could do something like this (untested):

```
kernel
    .BindFilter<ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .When((controllerContext, actionDescriptor) =>
        controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType.ToLower() == "post" &&
        typeof(baseController).IsAssignableFrom(actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType));
```